# Dynamically creating the IN clause in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help in dynamic query with IN Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845794/need-help-in-dynamic-query-with-in-clause)

I am using SQL server 2008 and this is the problem that I am facing. I have a table named Cars with a column Company. Now I have a stored procedure that looks something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindCars (@CompanyNames varchar(500))
AS
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Company IN (@CompanyNames)
```

I tried something like this and failed

```
DECLARE @CompanyNames varchar(500)
SET @CompanyNames = '''Ford'',''BMW'''

exec FindCars @CompanyNames
```

I dont get any rows returned. When I do the following

```
DECLARE @CompanyNames varchar(500)
SET @CompanyNames = '''Ford'',''BMW'''

Select @CompanyNames
```

I get the following result

```
'Ford','BMW'
```

and if I replace this value in the select statement inside the stored procedure, it works

```
SELECT * FROM Cars where Company in ('Ford','BMW')
```

Thus I think that the stored procedure seems to be treating `'Ford','BMW'` as one string rather than an array. Could someone please help me with this. How do I dynamically construct the string/array required in the IN clause of the select statement inside the stored procedure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, you created one string, and that is being processed as a list of strings that contains one string.  The commas are just characters in that one string.  The only equivilent to an array in SQL Server is a table.

For example; `WHERE x IN (SELECT y FROM z)`.

For this reason many people create a `SPLIT_STRING()` function that returns a table of items from a given comma delimitted string...

```
WHERE x IN (SELECT item FROM dbo.split_string(@input_string))
```

There are many ways to implement that split string.  Some return strings, some cast to integers, some accept a second "delimiter" parameter, etc, etc.  You can search the internet for `SQL SERVER SPLIT STRING` and get many results - Including here in StackOverflow.

An alternative is to use dynamic SQL; SQL that writes SQL.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM x WHERE y IN (' + @input_string_list + ')'

SP_EXECEUTESQL @sql
```

*(I recommend `SP_EXECUTESQL` over just `EXEC` because the former allows you to use parameterised queries, but the latter does not.)*

Comment: just to add a point, i think this is better `select * from cars
Inner join 
(
 SELECT item FROM dbo.split_string(@input_string)
)k
on K.Item = Company` because u are doing iteration using `IN` Predicate

Comment: The first method is the one I recommend, you can find a nice split function here:
[http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)