# Check to see if tables are present in a database - stored procedure - MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, space, delimited

I want the user to input whatever database they want to check and whatever tables they want to check. For example the call would look like this:

```
call tableCheck('MyDatabase', 'table1 table20 table3')
```

So the procedure would check for those tables (space delimited). I have my code down below but I am having problem checking the other tables, it reads the first but not the second or third one. SO my code is not looping or not reading the next word.

```
PROCEDURE `tableCheck` (db VARCHAR(256), db_tables VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN   
DECLARE tbl, tbls VARCHAR(256); 
DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 0;

SET tbls = db_tables;

    WHILE c = 0 DO

        #split word
        SET tbl = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbls," ",1);
        #go to next string
        SET tbls = SUBSTR(tbls,LENGTH(tbl)+1);

        #check every table
        SELECT table_name AS 'Table Name'
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  
        WHERE table_schema=db AND table_name=tbl;

        IF tbls = 0 THEN 
            SET c = 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Unless your tables start with numbers, `tbls = 0` will always be true.

Comment: I see so its always closing after the first loop. So I have to find another way for the loop to close. @Uueerdo

Comment: You could make your test something like this `tbls REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+'`

Comment: I've tried different variations of this but same result, either closes the loop right away or goes infinite @Uueerdo

Answer (score 0):

I have given this link out a few times today...so maybe it will work for you too.
[Convert a delimited string to a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32852200/357455)

Using the dbo.fnArray function from that link you should be able to join on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES like this:

```
create procedure dbo.spCheckTable @db varchar(256), @tbls varchar(8000)
as
begin
    select * 
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES i
     inner join dbo.fnArray(@tbls, ' ') t on i.TABLE_NAME = t.arrValue
     where i.TABLE_CATALOG = @db
end
```

Now its a stored procedure

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing but I want to avoid using functions. I want to keep it all in one stored procedure

Comment: Updated my solution so now its a stored procedure.  Not sure why you want to avoid functions.  Most people strive to implement DRY principles and other patterns.